# Windows Phone cut part of element (rectangle)

Tags: windows, windows-phone

I don't know how to cut center of element (do center of element clear [sorry for my english]). I think to use opacity mask but i can't create this. I need create like this[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FFFF0000" Height="100" Width="100" />

<Rectangle Fill="#FF00FF00" Height="100" Width="100">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="mask.png"/>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```